# get count data between each hour in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have two date fields `Start_time` and `End_time` with one entry for every 15 minutes. I want to pull out the data for each hour what is the count inserted.

```
Start_time                End_time                Records
05-OCT-14 10:00:00 AM   05-OCT-14 10:14:59 AM     10
05-OCT-14 10:15:00 AM   05-OCT-14 10:29:59 AM     20 
05-OCT-14 10:30:00 AM   05-OCT-14 10:44:59 AM     30     
05-OCT-14 10:45:00 AM   05-OCT-14 10:59:59 AM     40
05-OCT-14 11:00:00 AM   05-OCT-14 11:14:59 AM     10
05-OCT-14 11:15:00 AM   05-OCT-14 11:29:59 AM     50
05-OCT-14 11:30:00 AM   05-OCT-14 11:44:59 AM     50
05-OCT-14 11:45:00 AM   05-OCT-14 11:59:59 AM     50
```

I need to count how many records are there 10 to 10:59 and 11 to 11.59 etc. Like 10.00 to 10.59 count is 100

Comment: Which piece of data do you want to count?

Comment: I need to count how many records are there 10 to 10:59 and 11 to 11.59 etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  sum (record),TRUNC (start_time, 'hh')
FROM your_table
GROUP BY TRUNC (start_time, 'hh');
```

This results:

```
COUNT(*)         TRUNC(START_TIME,'HH')
  160              10/5/2014 11:00:00 AM
  100              10/5/2014 10:00:00 AM
```

This count rows grouping by hour. I hope this helps

Comment: As you can see first row is count between 11.00 to 11.59 and second row is the count between 10.00 to 10.59

Comment: Maybe we can add
    TRUNC(START_TIME + 1 / 24, 'HH') - 1 / 86400
to get the end time also.